# Barchart with more than one category

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer, report-designer

Iam creating charts with the `RDLC-Report Designer`. The charts are getting the data from a `dataset`. I Have the following chart:

[image]

As you can see, there is only one bar shown, and I want something like that:

[image]

More than one bar with different categories.
If I rightclick on the diagram, I have the option to modify categories, however, I do not know what to put in there.

How do I show more than one bar in this diagram with different data?

Thank you